# How to add LINK relations in executeQuery DataSource Form?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-365

In executeQuery DataSource method, how can I add a Table relation by code x++?

My code:

*I don't need to add the table My_Other_Table in forms DataSources, I would like to add the relation by code*

```
public void executeQuery()
{

   qbds_1                 = this.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(MyDataSourceTable));
   qbds_2 = 
   this.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(MyDataSourceTable)).addDataSource(tablenum(My_Other_Table));

  qbds_2.addLink(fieldnum(My_Other_Table,RecId), fieldnum(MyDataSourceTable, RecId));
  qbds_2.relations(true);
  qbds_2.joinMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin);
}
```

It doesn't work.

Please, could you give me the righ

Answer (score 1):

You want `.relations(false)`.

`True` tells the query to use the actual table relation in the AOT. In your case, it is telling the query to look for a relation on your `My_OtherTable` that refers to `MyDataSourceTable`, which in the AOT would be `\Data Dictionary\Tables\My_Other_Table\Relations\[Some Relation that is table MyDataSourceTable]`.